# Java Application disappears when using a native library

Tags: java, native, virtual-machine

I am running a Java application, which is connecting to Player/Stage (robot simulation program) via a native library. If I run the Java application and Player/Stage on the same Ubuntu PC everything works fine. But if I run the Java application and Player/Stage on Ubuntu VM an error appears. The Java application is shutting down without any error messages. The GUI disappears and Player/Stage is still running. The problem comes up when the Java application is trying to connect to Player/Stage. The same error occurs when I am run the Java application and Player/Stage on several Ubuntu PCs.

Afterwards Ubuntu wants to send a bug report which says:

> The crashed program seems to use third-party or local libraries:
>
> /usr/local/lib/liblibrary.so.0.0.0 /home/user/workspace/liblibrary.so
>
> It is highly recommended to check if the problem persists without
>   those first.

This error isn't helping at all, because I need the native libraries to connect these two programs.

Is there a possibility to read an error message anyhow? Are there some differences between java sun and openjdk?

**EDIT:** The solution was a little bit specific. The problem here is the stacksize. Because the library needs a bigger one then the normal one. So, I needed to add the command `-Xss16m` to get an higher stacksize. I can set this command in eclipse in Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs take the actual JRE->edit->then Default VM arguments. This is now working well for my Ubuntu distribution, but not for Windows 7 x32. Are there some other methods to set the stacksize for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The native library is crashing (most likely a seg fault).  Contact the creators of that library and find out what's going on.

One obvious thing to check for is the bitness of the library - is it 32 or 64 bit, and what is your operating system?  Beyond that, you are at the mercy of the library creator.

Comment: The strange thing is that the library does not crash at the same PC. The library is for x32 systems and I only run x32 systems. Thats not the problem.